# Dovecot 2.3 deb package for Raspbian Stretch Lite

Tags: raspbian

By default [Raspbian Stretch Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) comes with Dovecot 2.2.27 which [does not support BLF-CRYPT](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes) password scheme.  Does anybody know if there is a repository with Dovecot 2.3 for Raspbian Stretch Lite?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: dovecot 2.3.4 is present in the raspbian repository - I'm not sure how one would install it though - perhaps adding `buster` and do some pinning etc

Comment: @Jaromanda X, could you please post a URI for the repository you are referring to?  I only see 2.2.27 in this one: https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/

Comment: If you don't want to do @JaromandaX's update to add the Buster repo then you could pull all the 2.3 debs from http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/d/dovecot/

Comment: Of course, the question was `if there is a repository with Dovecot 2.3 for Raspbian Stretch Lite?` - to which the answer is, there isn't one

Comment: @Dougie  I tried installing manually deb files from mirrordirector link but the installed binaries required different versions of libc6, libicu63, liblua5.3-0, libsodium23 and libssl1.1, which Raspbian Stretch does not have.  I also rebuilt the kernel with CONFIG_CRYPTO_BLOWFISH=m, hoping that Dovecot would understand it through crypt library, but it didn't work :(

Comment: You'll have to wait for Buster. Or do the /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/preferences.d stuff as documented at https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

Comment: I setup Buster from https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi3 and ```doveadm pw -l``` shows ```BLF-CRYPT```  Thank you @JaromandaX and @Dougie!

Comment: Buster is too slow on Raspberry, and spamassassin runs out of memory.  Easier solution is to go back to Raspbian Stretch Lite, take sources of dovecot 2.3.4.1 and compile them directly on RaspberryPi device.  This gives BLF-CRYPT support.  Not sure why I didn't do this earlier :(